# link_to options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to make this into a link_to link:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Sign-In <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

I have this so far, but can't figure out how to handle the `<b class="caret"></b>`. I have tried a do block at the end of the `link_to`, but only got an error.

```
<%= link_to "Sign-In", new_user_session_path, :class => "dropdown-toggle", :data => {:toggle=>"dropdown"} %>
```

I've just started learning Rails, and have searched around (including reading the RoR API docs) but have got nothing to work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `link_to` that you provided is alright in terms of context.

Let me tell you what it is upto:

This is the link that you mentioned:

```
<%= link_to "Sign-In", new_user_session_path, :class => "dropdown-toggle", :data => {:toggle=>"dropdown"} %>
```

This is the corresponding html link formed by the above link_to:

```
<a href="users/sessions/new" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign-In</a>
```

Now consider this link:

```
<%= link_to(raw("Sign-In" +("<b class= 'caret'></b>")), new_user_session_path, :class => "dropdown-toggle", :data => {:toggle=>"dropdown"}) %>
```

The above link will give you the following html link:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="users/sessions/new">Sign-In<b class= 'caret'></b></a>
```

Now you are almost close to your result. The only thing is the href.

Ok let's modify the above `link_to` a bit with just a change in **href path** as-

```
<%= link_to(raw("Sign-In" +("<b class= 'caret'></b>")), "#", :class => "dropdown-toggle", :data => {:toggle=>"dropdown"}) %>
```

The generated link is now equivalent to what you wanted:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign-In<b class= 'caret'></b></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I didn't know anything about the raw tag

Comment: If I had more reputation, I would throw an upvote your way! Thanks again!

Comment: i have this in my tag data-original-title="Edit" and i am getting a error. it xpects a )

Answer (score 11):

If you provide a block, you omit the first argument (normally the content of the a tag) and it will be replaced by what the block yields.

```
<%= link_to new_user_session_path, :class => "dropdown-toggle", :data => {:toggle=>"dropdown"} do %>
  Sign-In <b class="caret"></b>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ahh, I knew the key was the block, but couldn't figure out the arguments and such. Thanks much mate!

Answer (score 0):

put the link in a container it could be a div and put a class ="dropdown".

```
 <div class="dropdown">
    <%= link_to image_tag('icons/lock_icon.png') + " Log In" +('<b class="caret"></b>').html_safe , '#', { :class => 'dropdown-toggle', 'data-toggle' =>  'dropdown' } %>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be a data attribute in link_to
`link_to remove_user_path(recipient_id: recipient.id) , method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete?'}`